# WordPress jQuery error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null"

Tags: jquery, wordpress, galleria

I've searched through a slew of tangentially related questions to this, but not precisely, so here goes:

I've been working on a site that's (unfortunately) using three different jQuery plugins in WordPress (image carousel on index, image gallery plugin "Galleria" on [Portfolio](http://www.cypresshilldevelopment.com/ourhomes_portfolio1/) pages, Custom Contact Form 7 on Contact Us page).

With some help I've been able to eliminate most of the errors it's been throwing me as a result, but I'm left now with a final one:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

I've split things up so that the following is called in header.php:

```
    <link href="http://www.cypresshilldevelopment.com/wp-content/themes/CHD2/galleria.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, print"/>
```

And then the rest is called in footer.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.cypresshilldevelopment.com/wp-content/themes/CHD2/galleria_wp/js/jquery.galleria.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $ = jQuery;
    $(function(){ $('ul.gallery').galleria({tempClass: 'active', thumbnail_caption: ''}); })
</script>

    <!-- script for jQuery image carousel -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/CHD2/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/CHD2/js/jquery.easing.compatibility.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/CHD2/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/CHD2/js/app.js"></script>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="supersleight-min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

What am I doing wrong here? Did I split up the code incorrectly? The error points to a line in the code WordPress is generating for the page defining a value for `wphc_value`, but for the life of me I haven't been able to find any reference to "wphc" in any php or js file being used.

Comment: Is that a PHP error or a JavaScript error? Looks like a JavaScript error but `wphc_value` appears to have something to do with the Wordpress Hashcash plugin.

Comment: I believe it's a JavaScript error, but could be wrong. I'm definitely not using the Hashcash plugin, although I did see that mentioned in a Google search for it as well. Yet another reason I'm thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the cause of the error message, but you need to load a theme (loadTheme) for Galleria before initializing it.

http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/getting_started/beginners_guide/

Also, don't know why you have `$ = jQuery;`, you probably don't need it.